# Fifos and interactive command (gpg)

Tags: linux, bash, fifo, gnupg

For use in a larger script, I am trying to use a fifo together with `gpg`. First I have an encrypted file `secrets.txt.gpg`

```
me@box:~$ touch secrets.txt
me@box:~$ echo 'first secret' > secrets.txt
me@box:~$ gpg -c secrets.txt
```

and a short pass phrase is entered twice ('easy').

Now I would like to decrypt the secrets file, add an element and do something with the result. To keep it simple I just eg. want to `cat` the result. Trying

```
me@box:~$ mkfifo fifo
me@box:~$ gpg -d secrets.txt.gpg > fifo &
[5] 9405
me@box:~$ echo 'second secret' > fifo &
[5] 9405
me@box:~$ cat < fifo
gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
second secret
```

leaves the shell unresponsive until `Ctrl-C`. I have tried with process substitution giving

```
 me@box:~$ cat <(gpg -d secrets.txt.gpg) <(echo 'second secret') > fifo &
 [7] 9422
 me@box:~$ gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
 Enter passphrase: easy
 bash: easy: command not found
 me@box:~$
```

How can I write the output to a pipe after decryption by `gpg -d`, add entries and later encrypt to disc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gpg` needs the passphrase before it will output the decrypted file. In the first example,

```
gpg -d secrets.txt.gpg > fifo &
```

the process is run in the background and so can't get the passphrase from the user. I found that

```
gpg --passphrase easy -d secrets.txt.gpg > fifo &
```

or

```
echo easy | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 -d secrets.txt.gpg > fifo &
```

would give the following output from `cat <fifo`:

```
gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: first secret
WARNING: message was not integrity protected
```